# Something like a LINQ provider

Tags: c#, repository, extension-methods, expression-trees

Ok, before you ask: **yes, I need to do this**. Sort of.

I'm wrapping a 3rd-party API for data access, and **I can't use an ORM**, so I'm implementing this kind of thing:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Projects all entities that match specified predicate into a <see cref="TEntity"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filter">A function expression that returns <c>true</c> for all entities to return.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Select(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter);

    /// <summary>
    /// Projects the single that matches specified predicate into a <see cref="TEntity"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown when predicate matches more than a single result.</exception>
    /// <param name="filter">A function expression that returns <c>true</c> for the only entity to return.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter);

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the underlying <see cref="View"/> for the specified entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The existing entity with the modified property values.</param>
    void Update(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the specified entity from the underlying <see cref="View"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The existing entity to remove.</param>
    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a new entity into the underlying <see cref="View"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">A non-existing entity to create in the system.</param>
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
}
```

Notice the `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter` parameter of the `Single` and `Select` methods? That's so I can write this:

> ```
> using (var repository = new PurchaseOrderRepository())
> {
>     var po = repository.Single(x => x.Number == "123456");
>     //...
> }
> ```

Instead of this:

> ```
> _headerView.Browse("PONUMBER = \"123456\"", true);
> ```

So, this `ToFilterExpression` extension method allows me to nicely wrap this *stringly-typed* API with my own *strongly-typed* API, and hide all the nastiness behind a familiar `IRepository` abstraction.

Here's the extension method in question:

```
public static string ToFilterExpression<TEntity>(this Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression) 
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)expression;
    lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)Evaluator.PartialEval(lambdaExpression);

    var visitor = new FilterVisitor<TEntity>(lambdaExpression);
    var result = visitor.Filter;

    return result;
}
```

If you're curious, here's what the client code looks like:

> ```
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     using (var session = new Session())
>     {
>         session.Init(/*redacted*/);
>         session.Open(/*redacted*/);
>
>         using (var context = session.OpenDBLink(DBLinkType.Company, DBLinkFlags.ReadWrite))
>         using (var repository = new PurchaseOrderHeadersRepository())
>         {
>             repository.Compose(context);
>             var poNumber = "123456";
>             var date = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
>             var result = repository.Select(x => x.Number == poNumber && x.OrderDate >= date || x.Number.EndsWith("123"));
>
>             foreach(var po in result)
>             {
>                 Console.WriteLine("PO Number: {0}", po.Number);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     Console.ReadLine();
> }
> ```

...which looks pretty neat compared to what it would be without that wrapper API! The extension method produces this output:

> ```
> "PONUMBER = 123456 AND ORDEREDON >= 20160105 OR PONUMBER LIKE \"%123\""
> ```

---

To achieve this, I implemented an `ExpressionVisitor`, adapting code from an MSDN article. Here's the visitor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx
/// </summary>
internal class FilterVisitor<TEntity> : ExpressionVisitor
    where TEntity : class, new()
{
    private readonly Expression _expression;
    private string _filter;
    private readonly IList<EntityPropertyInfo<TEntity>> _properties;

    public FilterVisitor(Expression expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
        _properties = typeof (TEntity).GetPropertyInfos<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_filter == null)
            {
                _filter = string.Empty;
                Visit(_expression);
            }
            return _filter;
        }
    }

    private readonly ExpressionType[] _binaryOperators =
    {
        ExpressionType.Equal,
        ExpressionType.NotEqual,
        ExpressionType.GreaterThan,
        ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual,
        ExpressionType.LessThan,
        ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual
    };

    private readonly IDictionary<ExpressionType, string> _binaryOperations = new Dictionary<ExpressionType, string>
    {
        { ExpressionType.Equal, " = " },
        { ExpressionType.NotEqual, " != " },
        { ExpressionType.GreaterThan, " > " },
        { ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, " >= " },
        { ExpressionType.LessThan, " < " },
        { ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual, " <= " },
        { ExpressionType.AndAlso, " AND " },
        { ExpressionType.OrElse, " OR " },
    };

    private readonly Stack<string> _operators = new Stack<string>();
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
    {
        if (_binaryOperators.Contains(b.NodeType))
        {
            foreach (var property in _properties)
            {
                var name = property.Property.Name;
                if (ExpressionTreeHelpers.IsMemberEqualsValueExpression(b, typeof(TEntity), name, b.NodeType))
                {
                    var value = ExpressionTreeHelpers.GetValueFromEqualsExpression(b, typeof(TEntity), name, b.NodeType);
                    if (value is DateTime)
                    {
                        value = ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                    }
                    _filter += property.FieldName + _binaryOperations[b.NodeType] + value;
                    if (_operators.Any())
                    {
                        _filter += _operators.Pop();
                    }
                    return b;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (b.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso || b.NodeType == ExpressionType.OrElse)
        {
            _operators.Push(_binaryOperations[b.NodeType]);
        }

        return base.VisitBinary(b);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(string))
        {
            if (m.Method.Name == "StartsWith")
            {
                foreach (var property in _properties)
                {
                    var name = property.Property.Name;
                    if (ExpressionTreeHelpers.IsSpecificMemberExpression(m.Object, typeof(TEntity), name))
                    {
                        _filter += property.FieldName + " LIKE \"" + ExpressionTreeHelpers.GetValueFromExpression(m.Arguments[0]) + "%\"";
                        return m;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (m.Method.Name == "EndsWith")
            {
                foreach (var property in _properties)
                {
                    var name = property.Property.Name;
                    if (ExpressionTreeHelpers.IsSpecificMemberExpression(m.Object, typeof(TEntity), name))
                    {
                        _filter += property.FieldName + " LIKE \"%" + ExpressionTreeHelpers.GetValueFromExpression(m.Arguments[0]) + "\"";
                        return m;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (m.Method.Name == "Contains")
            {
                foreach (var property in _properties)
                {
                    var name = property.Property.Name;
                    if (ExpressionTreeHelpers.IsSpecificMemberExpression(m.Object, typeof(TEntity), name))
                    {
                        _filter += property.FieldName + " LIKE \"%" + ExpressionTreeHelpers.GetValueFromExpression(m.Arguments[0]) + "%\"";
                        return m;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(m);
    }
}
```

Obviously there are a number of things I could add and support additional constructs and method calls - but this is pretty much *good enough* for my immediate needs.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you thought about sanitizing search strings? i.e. What if I supplied `x.Number.EndsWith("123\" OR \"1\"=\"1")`  would it return everything?

Comment: Well, the data is coming from two legacy systems, I'm not concerned with "search filter injection" at all.. though it might of course be a concern if I had, say, a world-facing web UI using it... but I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about the amount of things that aren't supported (yet/if ever) - it's impossible to cover everything in a scenario like this. One thing I would suggest is that you throw exceptions so the caller knows they're doing something unexpected:

```
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
{
    if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(string))
    {
        // might work better as a switch with a default case. 
        if (m.Method.Name == "StartsWith")
        {
            // ...
        }
        if (m.Method.Name == "EndsWith")
        {
            // ...
        }
        if (m.Method.Name == "Contains")
        {
            // ...
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException("A meaningful error message");
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException("A meaningful error message");
}
```

---

"LIKE" should be a well named constant.

---

String.Format or string interpolation is nicer than concatenation:

```
var value = expressionTreeHelpers.GetValueFromExpression(m.Arguments[0]);
_filter += $"{property.FieldName} LIKE \"%{value}\"";
```

---

I'm afraid that's about the limit of what I can suggest at the moment. It *seems* like a good approach to me **but** I'm not exactly an expert at this kind of thing! I would suggest putting some search string validation/escaping in as it's generally a good idea to be cautious.

Comment: OMG this pretty much deserves a bounty. The lack of exceptions was causing the extension method to silently return an empty filter string, which made the `Select` call return every single entity. Thanks!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Glad it helped! :)

Comment: What would be really awesome is if, instead of throwing an exception right away, I would try to resolve the method call to a constant expression, and only throw when *that* is impossible. That way I wouldn't be throwing on, say, `x => x.Description.Contains(foobar.ToLower())`; I'd *evaluate* `foobar.ToLower()` instead. hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're referring to methods on string, you could use the `nameof` operator:

```
if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(string))
{
    if (m.Method.Name == nameof(string.StartsWith))
    {
        // ...
    }
    if (m.Method.Name == nameof(string.EndsWith))
    {
        // ...
    }
    if (m.Method.Name == nameof(string.Contains))
    {
        // ...
    }
```

If/when you add more supported methods, you get the intellisense for the method names as a result.

Comment: Nice one. Too bad I'm not using C# 6 for this.