# Linq-to-Sage Implementation

Tags: c#, linq, api, reflection, expression-trees

Following-up on my [last question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/118970/23788) where I wrapped the Sage API with a familiar `IRepository` interface, I decided to push the abstraction a step further, and... implement an *actual* LINQ provider.

So my client code looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new SageContext(/*redacted*/))
        {
            context.Open();
            var orders =
                from po in context.PurchaseOrderHeaders
                where po.Number.Contains("123") && po.Lines > 0
                select po;

            foreach (var po in orders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PO Number: {0} ({1:d}) - {2}", po.Number, po.OrderDate, po.Key);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Looks exactly like it would with Entity Framework? That's intentional. Except... I don't have fancypants navigation properties. Yet (to be honest, not sure I have the slightest idea of how I'd go about this).

So, a bare-bones `SageContext` looks like this:

```
public class SageContext : SageContextBase
{
    public SageContext(string userId, string password, string dbName) 
        : base(new SageCredential(userId, password, dbName))
    {
    }

    public ViewSet<PurchaseOrderHeader> PurchaseOrderHeaders { get; set; }
    public ViewSet<PurchaseOrderHeaderOptionalField> PurchaseOrderHeaderOptionalFields { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelComposing()
    {
        //PurchaseOrderHeaders.View.Compose(new View[]{ /*compose views here*/ });
    }
}
```

Every `ViewSet<TEntity>` property is assigned a reference via reflection, in the base class (does that interfere with `IDisposable`?) - the `SageCredential` class isn't secure at all, I just added it because it nicely wraps closely-related values into a single-use object:

```
public abstract class SageContextBase : IDisposable
{
    private const string AppId = "ABC";
    private const string ProgramName = "ABC1234";
    private const string AppVersion = "999";

    private readonly SageCredential _credential;
    private readonly Session _session;
    private DBLink _db;

    protected SageContextBase(SageCredential credential)
    {
        _session = new Session();
        _credential = credential;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the database connection and initializes the <see cref="ViewSet{TEntity}"/> members.
    /// </summary>
    public void Open()
    {
        _session.Init(string.Empty, AppId, ProgramName, AppVersion);
        _session.Open(_credential.UserId, _credential.Password, _credential.DatabaseName, DateTime.Now, 0);
        _db = _session.OpenDBLink(DBLinkType.Company, DBLinkFlags.ReadWrite);

        var properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                  .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.PropertyType.IsGenericType);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var entityType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            var view = AddView(GetMappedViewId(entityType));

            var constructedType = typeof (ViewSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
            var viewSetInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType, view);

            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, viewSetInstance);
        }

        OnModelComposing();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a hook for derived types to specify how views are composed.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void OnModelComposing();

    private readonly IDictionary<string, IViewComInterop> _views = new Dictionary<string, IViewComInterop>();

    private IViewComInterop AddView(string viewId)
    {
        if (_views.ContainsKey(viewId))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("View '" + viewId + "' is already added.");
        }

        _views[viewId] = _db.OpenView(viewId);
        return _views[viewId];
    }

    // Executes the expression tree that is passed to it. 
    internal static object Execute<TEntity>(Expression expression, ViewSet<TEntity> viewSet)
    {

        // The expression must represent a query over the data source. 
        if (!(expression is MethodCallExpression))
        {
            throw new InvalidProgramException("No query over the data source was specified.");
        }

        // Find the call to Where() and get the lambda expression predicate.
        var whereFinder = new InnermostWhereFinder();
        var whereExpression = whereFinder.GetInnermostWhere(expression);
        var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)(whereExpression.Arguments[1])).Operand;

        // Send the lambda expression through the partial evaluator.
        lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)Evaluator.PartialEval(lambdaExpression);

        // Get the filter string to pass to the Sage API.
        var visitor = new FilterVisitor<TEntity>(lambdaExpression.Body);
        var filter = visitor.Filter;

        return viewSet.Select(filter);
    }


    private static string GetMappedViewId(Type type)
    {
        var mapsToView = type.GetCustomAttribute<MapsToAttribute>();
        if (mapsToView == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Entity type is missing a MapsToAttribute.");
        }
        return mapsToView.Name;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var view in _views.Values)
        {
            view.Dispose();
        }

        _db.Dispose();
        _session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And the rest of the magic happens in the `ViewSet<TEntity>` class, which replaces my old `RepositoryBase<TEntity>` base type:

```
public sealed class ViewSet<TEntity> : IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> 
{
    public ViewSet(IViewComInterop view)
    {
        _view = view;
        Provider = new SageQueryProvider<TEntity>(view);
        Expression = Expression.Constant(this);
    }

    public ViewSet(SageQueryProvider<TEntity> provider, Expression expression, IViewComInterop view)
    {
        if (provider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");
        }

        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        }

        if (!typeof (IQueryable<TEntity>).IsAssignableFrom(expression.Type))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("expression");
        }

        _view = view;

        Provider = provider;
        Expression = expression;
    }

    private readonly IViewComInterop _view;
    public IViewComInterop View { get { return _view; } }

    public IEnumerator<TEntity> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (Provider.Execute<IEnumerable>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider { get; private set; }
    public Expression Expression { get; private set; }

    public Type ElementType { get { return typeof (TEntity); } }

    private TEntity ReadEntity()
    {
        var result = (TEntity)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TEntity));
        var properties = result.GetPropertyInfos();

        foreach (var property in properties.Where(property => property.ViewName == View.ViewID))
        {
            var value = View.Fields.FieldByName(property.FieldName).Value;
            property.Property.SetValue(result, value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<TEntity> Select(string filter)
    {
        View.Browse(filter, true);

        if (!View.GoTop())
        {
            yield break;
        }

        do
        {
            yield return ReadEntity();
        }
        while (View.GoNext());
    }

    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As you can see I still haven't implemented the rest of the CRUD operations - but *now* I'm happy enough about how this is set up, to do it.

Extending this code means following the Application Object Model specs and creating classes that map to each <s>table</s> *View*, and by decorating members with a `MapsToAttribute`, everything "just works".

```
/// <summary>
/// An attribute that maps an entity type to a specific Sage view object,
/// or an entity property to a specific field in that view.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MapsToAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _name;

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps an entity type to a specific Sage view,
    /// or an entity property to a specific field in that view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the mapped view or field.</param>
    public MapsToAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the mapped view or field.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
}
```

But the real magic is here:

```
public class SageQueryProvider<TEntity> : IQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IViewComInterop _view;

    public SageQueryProvider(IViewComInterop view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        try
        {
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (ViewSet<TEntity>).MakeGenericType(elementType), this, expression, _view);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException exception)
        {
            throw exception.InnerException;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<TResult> CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        return (IQueryable<TResult>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ViewSet<>).MakeGenericType(elementType), this, expression, _view);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return SageContextBase.Execute(expression, new ViewSet<TEntity>(_view));
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return (TResult)SageContextBase.Execute(expression, new ViewSet<TEntity>(_view));
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure how I feel about the `new ViewSet<TEntity>(_view))` going on here, but... it works.

Any & all feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of missed opportunities that could be considered as bugs here.

---

Your `Execute<TEntity>` implementation in `SageContextBase` is poorly adapted from the MSDN example. Good job on making it generic, but this:

> ```
> // The expression must represent a query over the data source. 
> if (!(expression is MethodCallExpression))
> {
>     throw new InvalidProgramException("No query over the data source was specified.");
> }
> ```

..is causing a weird issue. Consider:

```
var orders = from po in context.PurchaseOrderHeaders select po;
```

and:

```
var orders = context.PurchaseOrders;
```

Are these two snippets equivalent? No! The second one is a `ConstantExpression` without a `MethodCallExpression`, which makes your `Execute` method throw a surprising exception whenever there isn't an explicit projection / `Select` call.

Additionally, this part:

> ```
>     // Find the call to Where() and get the lambda expression predicate.
>     var whereFinder = new InnermostWhereFinder();
>     var whereExpression = whereFinder.GetInnermostWhere(expression);
>     var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)(whereExpression.Arguments[1])).Operand;
> ```

Assumes there's always a `Where` clause in your query, which you probably don't want to assume, especially if you're simply selecting all rows from a small support view/table.

You can account for the `ConstantExpression` like this:

```
var constantExpression = expression as ConstantExpression;
if (constantExpression != null)
{
    if (constantExpression.Value is ViewSet<TEntity>)
    {
        return viewSet.Select(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

And you can account for a missing `Where` clause with a simple null check, like this:

```
var whereFinder = new InnermostWhereFinder();
var whereExpression = whereFinder.GetInnermostWhere(expression);
var filter = string.Empty;
if (whereExpression != null)
{
```

And now your client code can have this rather intuitive code run without any issues:

```
var foo = context.SomeEntity.ToList();
```

---

You haven't listed the `InnermostWhereFinder` class, but by the naming of the local variables involved I suspect it's not accounting for other filtering methods, and so these queries would throw potentially surprising exceptions:

```
var foo = context.Something.Single(s => s.Id == 42);
var foo = context.Something.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == 42);
var foo = context.Something.First(s => s.Id == 42);
var foo = context.Something.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 42);
var foo = context.Something.Last(s => s.Id == 42);
var foo = context.Something.LastOrDefault(s => s.Id == 42);
var foo = context.Something.Count(s => s.Foo == "42");
var foo = context.Something.Any();
var foo = context.Something.All(s => s.IsActive);
```

The provider should delegate anything it can't handle to LINQ-to-Objects, instead of blowing up. Matt Warren has a series of [articles on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-series) that go into more details than the little [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb546158%28v=vs.140%29) you used to do this.