# Testing an abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocks

I started writing a set of tests for my `SageContextBase` class, which needs to be `abstract` because the client code *must* derive from it (think of it as EF's `DbContext` - it can't be instantiated directly, but it packs a truckload of functionality) - I have 5 passing tests covering everything that should be happening inside the `Open` method:

```
[TestClass]
public class SageContextBaseOpenTests
{
    private Mock<IView> GetMockView(string viewId)
    {
        var view = new Mock<IView>();
        view.SetupAllProperties();
        view.SetupGet(m => m.ViewId).Returns(viewId);
        view.Setup(m => m.Compose(It.IsAny<IView[]>()));
        view.Setup(m => m.Dispose());
        view.Setup(m => m.Insert());
        view.Setup(m => m.Delete());
        view.Setup(m => m.Update());
        view.Setup(m => m.FilterCount(It.IsAny<string>()));

        return view;
    }

    private Mock<ISession> GetMockSession()
    {
        var dbLink = new Mock<IDbLink>();
        dbLink.SetupAllProperties();

        const string headersViewId = "PO0620";
        var headersView = GetMockView(headersViewId);
        dbLink.Setup(m => m.OpenView(headersViewId)).Returns(headersView.Object);

        const string detailsViewId = "PO0630";
        var detailsView = GetMockView(detailsViewId);
        dbLink.Setup(m => m.OpenView(detailsViewId)).Returns(detailsView.Object);

        var session = new Mock<ISession>();
        session.SetupAllProperties();
        session.Setup(m => m.OpenDbLink(It.IsAny<DBLinkType>(), It.IsAny<DBLinkFlags>())).Returns(dbLink.Object);

        return session;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Open_InitializesSessionWithSpecifiedAppInfo()
    {
        // arrange
        var credentials = new SageCredential("testuser", "testpwd", "testdb");
        var appInfo = new SageAppInfo("testapp", "v42");

        var session = GetMockSession();
        var context = new TestSageContext(credentials, appInfo, session.Object);

        // act
        context.Open();

        // assert
        session.Verify(m => m.Init(It.IsAny<string>(), appInfo));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Open_OpensSessionWithSpecifiedCredentials()
    {
        // arrange
        var credentials = new SageCredential("testuser", "testpwd", "testdb");
        var appInfo = new SageAppInfo("testapp", "v42");

        var session = GetMockSession();
        var context = new TestSageContext(credentials, appInfo, session.Object);

        // act
        context.Open();

        // assert
        session.Verify(m => m.Open(credentials, It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<int>()));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Open_OpensDbLinkWithCompanyAndReadWriteFlags()
    {
        // arrange
        var credentials = new SageCredential("testuser", "testpwd", "testdb");
        var appInfo = new SageAppInfo("testapp", "v42");

        var session = GetMockSession();
        var context = new TestSageContext(credentials, appInfo, session.Object);

        // act
        context.Open();

        // assert
        session.Verify(m => m.OpenDbLink(DBLinkType.Company, DBLinkFlags.ReadWrite));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Open_CreatesViewSetInstances()
    {
        // arrange
        var credentials = new SageCredential("testuser", "testpwd", "testdb");
        var appInfo = new SageAppInfo("testapp", "v42");

        var session = GetMockSession();
        var context = new TestSageContext(credentials, appInfo, session.Object);

        if (context.ViewSets.Any())
        {
            Assert.Inconclusive("Context.ViewSets collection must initialize empty.");
        }

        var properties = typeof (TestSageContext).GetProperties()
            .Where(property => property.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                               && property.CanRead && property.CanWrite
                               && property.GetMethod.IsPublic
                               && property.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                               && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name == typeof(ViewSet).Name + "`1")
            .ToList();

        var expected = properties.Count;

        // act
        context.Open();

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, context.ViewSets.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Open_CallsOnModelCreating()
    {
        // arrange
        var credentials = new SageCredential("testuser", "testpwd", "testdb");
        var appInfo = new SageAppInfo("testapp", "v42");

        var session = GetMockSession();
        var context = new TestSageContext(credentials, appInfo, session.Object);

        // act
        context.Open();

        // assert
        Assert.IsTrue(context.IsModelComposed);
    }
}
```

These tests use a fake implementation of the abstract class I'm testing:

```
class TestSageContext : SageContextBase
{
    public TestSageContext(SageCredential credential, SageAppInfo appInfo, ISession session) 
        : base(credential, appInfo, session)
    {
    }

    public ViewSet<PO0620> PurchaseOrderHeaders { get; set; }
    public ViewSet<PO0630> PurchaseOrderDetails { get; set; }

    public bool IsModelComposed { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnModelComposing()
    {
        PurchaseOrderHeaders.Compose(null, PurchaseOrderDetails, null, null, null);
        PurchaseOrderDetails.Compose(PurchaseOrderHeaders, null, null, null, null, null);

        IsModelComposed = true;
    }
}
```

Here's the method under test, and a few relevant members - note that the entire class is up for review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/121254/23788):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the database connection and initializes the <see cref="ViewSet{TEntity}"/> members.
    /// </summary>
    public void Open()
    {
        _session.Init(string.Empty, _info);
        _session.Open(_credential, DateTime.Now);
        _db = _session.OpenDbLink(DBLinkType.Company, DBLinkFlags.ReadWrite);

        var properties = GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite
                        && p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && p.CanRead
                        && p.CanWrite
                        && p.GetMethod.IsPublic
                        && p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                        && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name == typeof (ViewSet).Name + "`1");

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var entityType = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            var view = AddView(GetMappedViewId(entityType));

            var constructedType = typeof (ViewSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
            var viewSetInstance = (ViewSet)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedType, view, this);

            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, viewSetInstance);
            _viewSets.Add(viewSetInstance);
        }

        OnModelComposing();
    }

    private readonly IList<ViewSet> _viewSets = new List<ViewSet>(); 
    public IReadOnlyList<ViewSet> ViewSets { get { return _viewSets.ToList(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a hook for derived types to specify how views are composed.
    /// </summary>
    protected abstract void OnModelComposing();
```

I'm particularly interested in the implementation of the last test, which verifies whether the `OnModelComposing` method was called... but as always, any & all feedback is welcome.

Comment: What I typically do is thoroughly test the first implementation of an abstract class and leave a comment explaining why the other ones aren't as thoroughly tested. FWIW. For some reason, I'd never thought of creating a dummy implementation to test the base. ++

Comment: Rubberduck in this case the implementing code is client code that's not yet written (except some dummy F5-test console app code); I want to test the guts out of this one *before* I actually use it.

Comment: It gets harder and harder to review your code.

Comment: `Open_CallsOnModelCreating` looks like it should really be `Open_CallsOnModelComposing` something to watch during refactoring possibly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of things.

You repeat this set up in every test.

> ```
>     var credentials = new SageCredential("testuser", "testpwd", "testdb");
>     var appInfo = new SageAppInfo("testapp", "v42");
> ```

Extract the fixtures into fields and create a `[TestInitialize]` routine. If you need to change them later, then you have a different fixture and should create a new test class anyway. It helps to keep your test classes small, focused, and clean.

The `It.IsAny()` method is useful for getting your test to initially *pass*, but I get hesitant when I see it sticking around in code that's "done". I get *doubly* hesitant when I see it in a `Verify()`.

> ```
> session.Verify(m => m.Init(It.IsAny<string>(), appInfo));
> ```

It could be perfectly *ok*, but always worth a second look. It's a balancing act between making sure the tests go red if a breaking change is made, and *not* testing the implementation.

In a perfect world, we'd never have to `Verify()` anything. We would just `Assert` the output. We don't live in a perfect world, so this all might be fine, but it's definitely worth reflecting on.