# Loading and updating data from system A to system B

Tags: c#, linq

I need to transfer purchase order (PO) information from SQL Server into **Sage 300 ERP**, so using my [**Linq-to-Sage**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/119339/23788) implementation, I wrote a little console application that connects to a SQL Server database to fetch PO header information, including some metadata telling me whether a purchase order...

- is new and should be *created* in Sage
- has been modified and should be *updated* in Sage, or
- was removed from the source system and needs to be *deleted* from Sage

The `Program` class looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var credentials = new SageCredential(SageSettings.Default.SageUserName, SageSettings.Default.SageUserPwd, SageSettings.Default.SageDb);
        using (var context = new SageContext(credentials))
        {
            context.Open();
            var app = new App(context, new PurchaseOrderLoader());
            app.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The `SageContext` class implements a simple `IUnitOfWork` interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void SaveChanges();
    IViewSet<T> Set<T>() where T : EntityBase;
}
```

The `IPurchaseOrderLoader` interface merely abstracts away some ADO.NET operations that fetch data from the SQL Server source, and update the metadata by marking a processed record as such:

```
public interface IPurchaseOrderLoader
{
    IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderHeader> GetPurchaseOrderHeaders();
    void MarkProcessedPurchaseOrderHeader(int id);

    IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> GetPurchaseOrderDetails(string number);
    void MarkProcessedPurchaseOrderDetail(int id);
}
```

So here's the `App` class that encapsulates the whole logic:

```
public class App
{
    private static readonly string LastRevisionOptionalFieldName = PurchaseOrderHeader.OptionalFieldNames[PurchaseOrderHeader.OptionalField.RevisionDate];

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IPurchaseOrderLoader _loader;

    public App(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IPurchaseOrderLoader loader)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _loader = loader;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // performing projection with Linq-to-Objects, since Linq-to-Sage won't handle this:
        var vendorCodes = new HashSet<string>(_unitOfWork.Set<Vendor>().ToList().Select(e => e.Key));

        var headers = _loader.GetPurchaseOrderHeaders();
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> details = new PurchaseOrderDetail[] { };
            if (!vendorCodes.Contains(header.VendorCode))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("PO #{0} is referring to invalid vendor code '{1}'; PO is being skipped.", header.Number, header.VendorCode);
                continue;
            }

            if (ProcessHeader(header))
            {
                details = _loader.GetPurchaseOrderDetails(header.Number).OrderBy(e => e.LineNumber);
                ProcessDetails(details, header);
            }

            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Committing transaction for PO #" + header.Number);
                _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
                MarkProcessedEntities(header, details);
            }
            catch (SageSessionException exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ProcessHeader(PurchaseOrderHeader header)
    {
        var repository = _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderHeader>();
        var result = true;
        var existingHeader = repository.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Number == header.Number);

        if (existingHeader == null && !header.IsDeleted)
        {
            CreateNewHeaderRecord(header);
        }
        else if (existingHeader != null && !(new HeaderModifiedComparer()).Equals(header, existingHeader) && !header.IsDeleted)
        {
            UpdateExistingHeader(existingHeader, header);
        }
        else if (existingHeader != null && header.IsDeleted)
        {
            repository.Remove(existingHeader);
            result = false; // no need to process details, deleting the header will delete the details.
        }

        if (header.Key == 0 && existingHeader != null)
        {
            header.Key = existingHeader.Key;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void ProcessDetails(IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> details, PurchaseOrderHeader header)
    {
        var existingDetails = GetExistingDetails(header.Number).ToList();

        foreach (var detail in details)
        {
            var existingDetail = existingDetails.SingleOrDefault(e => DetailModifiedComparer.LineNumberEquals(e.LineNumber, detail.LineNumber));
            if (existingDetail != null)
            {
                detail.PurchaseOrderHeaderKey = existingDetail.PurchaseOrderHeaderKey;
            }

            if (existingDetail == null && !detail.IsDeleted)
            {
                CreateNewDetailRecord(header, detail);
            }
            else if (!(new DetailModifiedComparer()).Equals(detail, existingDetail) && !detail.IsDeleted)
            {
                UpdateExistingDetail(existingDetail, detail);
            }
            else if (existingDetail != null && detail.IsDeleted && !header.IsDeleted)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderDetail>().Remove(detail);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> GetExistingDetails(string headerNumber)
    {
        var header = _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderHeader>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Number == headerNumber);
        return header == null
            ? new PurchaseOrderDetail[] {}
            : header.Details;
    }

    private void CreateNewHeaderRecord(PurchaseOrderHeader header)
    {
        // "last modified" date is stored in an optional field:
        var revisionDate = new PO0623
        {
            FieldName = LastRevisionOptionalFieldName,
            FieldType = OptionalFieldType.Date,
            DateValue = DateTime.Now
        };

        header.OptionalFields.Add(revisionDate);
        _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderHeader>().Add(header);
    }

    private void UpdateExistingHeader(PurchaseOrderHeader existingHeader, PurchaseOrderHeader header)
    {
        // PO header exists in Sage AND is deemed modified: update it.
        existingHeader.FreeOnBoardPoint = header.FreeOnBoardPoint;
        existingHeader.IsOnHold = header.IsOnHold;
        existingHeader.OrderDate = header.OrderDate;
        existingHeader.Type = header.Type;

        var revisionDate = existingHeader.OptionalFields.SingleOrDefault(e => e.FieldName == LastRevisionOptionalFieldName);
        if (revisionDate != null)
        {
            revisionDate.DateValue = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    private void CreateNewDetailRecord(PurchaseOrderHeader header, PurchaseOrderDetail detail)
    {
        detail.PurchaseOrderHeaderKey = header.Key;
        header.Details.Add(detail);
        // Linq-to-Sage entity tracker doesn't subclass entity types, 
        // so it can't know about the added entity and thus we need to attach the detail entity manually:
        _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderDetail>().Attach(detail, EntityState.Added);
    }

    private void UpdateExistingDetail(PurchaseOrderDetail existingDetail, PurchaseOrderDetail detail)
    {
        existingDetail.QuantityOrdered = detail.QuantityOrdered;
        existingDetail.UnitWeight = detail.UnitWeight;
        existingDetail.UnitCost = detail.UnitCost;
    }

    private void MarkProcessedEntities(PurchaseOrderHeader header, IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> details)
    {
        _loader.MarkProcessedPurchaseOrderHeader(header.Id);
        foreach (var detail in details)
        {
            _loader.MarkProcessedPurchaseOrderDetail(detail.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

All this code was originally implemented as `static` methods in the `Program` class, so as you can see the refactoring is well under way.

Aside from some annoying things I need to fix in my LINQ provider, there's a specific thing I'm not very happy about:

> ```
> if (ProcessHeader(header))
> {
>     details = _loader.GetPurchaseOrderDetails(header.Number).OrderBy(e => e.LineNumber);
>     ProcessDetails(details, header);
> }
> ```

If, while processing the header, I notice I have nothing to do with detail records, I just skip them. The problem is with *how* that was implemented: I don't like that I have a `bool ProcessHeader` and then a `void ProcessDetails` method. Is there not a better way to do this?

Anything else looks weird? Say I'd want to write a thorough test suite for this code, should I extract more types? Is `App` doing too many things?

Answer (score 3):

Let's get straight to your main point about the `bool ProcessHeader()` method.

The first thing which popped in my head had been the multiple checks for null about `existingHeader`. Only the first `if` condition may do something if `existingHeader == null` so let us refactor this under the assumption we don't need the returned `bool` state, like so

```
    if (existingHeader == null)
    {
        if (!header.IsDeleted)
        {
            CreateNewHeaderRecord(header);
        }
        return;
    }
```

leaving the remaining code like so

```
    if (!(new HeaderModifiedComparer()).Equals(header, existingHeader) && !header.IsDeleted)
    {
        UpdateExistingHeader(existingHeader, header);
    }
    else if (header.IsDeleted)
    {
        repository.Remove(existingHeader);
    }

    if (header.Key == 0)
    {
        header.Key = existingHeader.Key;
    }
```

Now we switch the `if` conditions like so

```
    if (header.IsDeleted)
    {
        repository.Remove(existingHeader);
    }
    else if (!(new HeaderModifiedComparer()).Equals(header, existingHeader))
    {
        UpdateExistingHeader(existingHeader, header);
    }

    if (header.Key == 0)
    {
        header.Key = existingHeader.Key;
    }
```

If we now take a look at the former comment `// no need to process details, deleting the header will delete the details.` this can boil down to

```
private void ProcessHeader(PurchaseOrderHeader header)
{
    var repository = _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderHeader>();

    var existingHeader = repository.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Number == header.Number);

    if (existingHeader == null)
    {
        if (!header.IsDeleted)
        {
            CreateNewHeaderRecord(header);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (header.IsDeleted)
    {
        repository.Remove(existingHeader);
    }
    else if (!(new HeaderModifiedComparer()).Equals(header, existingHeader))
    {
        UpdateExistingHeader(existingHeader, header);
    }

    if (header.Key == 0)
    {
        header.Key = existingHeader.Key;
    } 
}
```

and now the calling code in question can look like so

```
ProcessHeader(header);
if (!header.IsDeleted)
{
    details = _loader.GetPurchaseOrderDetails(header.Number).OrderBy(e => e.LineNumber);
    ProcessDetails(details, header);
}
```

But IMO this doesn't look that good. Let us define an overloaded `ProcessDetails(PurchaseOrderHeader)` like so

```
private void ProcessDetails(PurchaseOrderHeader header)
{
    if (header.IsDeleted)
    {
        // no need to process details, deleting the header will delete the details.  
        return;
    }

    var details = _loader.GetPurchaseOrderDetails(header.Number).OrderBy(e => e.LineNumber).ToArray();
    ProcessDetails(details, header);
}
```

which leaves the `Start()` method like so

```
public void Start()
{
    // performing projection with Linq-to-Objects, since Linq-to-Sage won't handle this:
    var vendorCodes = new HashSet<string>(_unitOfWork.Set<Vendor>().ToList().Select(e => e.Key));

    var headers = _loader.GetPurchaseOrderHeaders();
    foreach (var header in headers)
    {

        if (!vendorCodes.Contains(header.VendorCode))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("PO #{0} is referring to invalid vendor code '{1}'; PO is being skipped.", header.Number, header.VendorCode);
            continue;
        }

        ProcessHeader(header);
        ProcessDetails(header);

        Debug.WriteLine("Committing transaction for PO #" + header.Number);
        try
        {
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            MarkProcessedEntities(header, details);
        }
        catch (SageSessionException exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

The `ProcessDetails()` could use a facelifting as well. We should use the fact that if `header.IsDeleted` this method won't be executed at all and rearange the `if` conditions a little bit like so

```
private void ProcessDetails(IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> details, PurchaseOrderHeader header)
{
    var existingDetails = GetExistingDetails(header.Number).ToList();

    foreach (var detail in details)
    {
        var existingDetail = existingDetails.SingleOrDefault(e => DetailModifiedComparer.LineNumberEquals(e.LineNumber, detail.LineNumber));
        if (existingDetail == null)
        {
            if (!detail.IsDeleted)
            {
                CreateNewDetailRecord(header, detail);
            }
            continue;
        }

        detail.PurchaseOrderHeaderKey = existingDetail.PurchaseOrderHeaderKey;

        if (detail.IsDeleted)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderDetail>().Remove(detail);
        }
        else if (!(new DetailModifiedComparer()).Equals(detail, existingDetail))
        {
            UpdateExistingDetail(existingDetail, detail);
        }

    }
}
```

---

Instead of the `new PurchaseOrderDetail[] {}` here

> ```
> private IEnumerable<PurchaseOrderDetail> GetExistingDetails(string headerNumber)
> {
>     var header = _unitOfWork.Set<PurchaseOrderHeader>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Number == headerNumber);
>     return header == null
>         ? new PurchaseOrderDetail[] {}
>         : header.Details;
> }
> ```

you should consider to use `Enumerable.Empty<PurchaseOrderDetail>`.