# LINQ Provider: Supporting Projections

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, linq-expressions

Up until recently, my LINQ-to-Sage provider didn't support *projections*, so the client code had to explicitly "transfer" to LINQ-to-Objects, like this:

> ```
> var vendorCodes = context.Vendors.ToList().Select(e => e.Code);
> ```

Now, with a bit of [help from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845667/how-to-make-linq-to-objects-handle-projections#comment63153906_37845667), I was able to modify my `IQueryProvider` implementation to support this:

> ```
> var vendorCodes = context.Vendors.Select(e => e.Code);
> ```

Or even this:

> ```
> var vendors = context.Vendors.Select(e => new { e.Code, e.Name });
> ```

Under the hood it's still LINQ-to-Objects handling it. Here's the `IQueryProvider` implementation:

```
public class SageQueryProvider<TEntity> : IQueryProvider
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    private readonly IView _view;
    private readonly SageContextBase _context;

    public SageQueryProvider(IView view, SageContextBase context)
    {
        _view = view;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        try
        {
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (ViewSet<TEntity>).MakeGenericType(elementType), _view, this, expression, _context);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException exception)
        {
            throw exception.InnerException;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<TResult> CreateQuery<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        var elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        if (elementType == typeof(EntityBase))
        {
            Debug.Assert(elementType == typeof (TResult));
            return (IQueryable<TResult>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ViewSet<>).MakeGenericType(elementType), _view, this, expression, _context);
        }

        var methodCallExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
        if(methodCallExpression != null && methodCallExpression.Method.Name == "Select")
        {
            return (IQueryable<TResult>)Execute(methodCallExpression);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Expression '{0}' is not supported by this provider.", expression));
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return Execute(expression, new ViewSet<TEntity>(_view, _context));
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return (TResult)Execute(expression, new ViewSet<TEntity>(_view, _context));
    }

    private static object Execute<T>(Expression expression, ViewSet<T> viewSet)
        where T : EntityBase
    {
        var constantExpression = expression as ConstantExpression;
        if (constantExpression != null)
        {
            if (constantExpression.Value is ViewSet<T>)
            {
                return viewSet.Select(string.Empty);
            }
        }

        var filterFinder = new InnermostFilterFinder();
        var filterExpression = filterFinder.GetInnermostFilter(expression);
        var filter = string.Empty;
        if (filterExpression != null)
        {
            if (filterExpression.Arguments.Count > 1)
            {
                var lambdaExpression =
                    (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)(filterExpression.Arguments[1])).Operand;

                // Send the lambda expression through the partial evaluator.
                lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)Evaluator.PartialEval(lambdaExpression);

                // Get the filter string to pass to the Sage API.
                var visitor = new FilterVisitor<T>(lambdaExpression.Body);
                filter = visitor.Filter;
            }

            switch (filterExpression.Method.Name)
            {
                case "Where":
                    return viewSet.Select(filter);
                case "Single":
                    var singleResult = viewSet.SingleOrDefault(filter);
                    if (singleResult == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains more than one element.");
                    }
                    return singleResult;
                case "SingleOrDefault":
                    return viewSet.SingleOrDefault(filter);
                case "First":
                    var firstResult = viewSet.FirstOrDefault(filter);
                    if (firstResult == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no element matching specified criteria.");
                    }
                    return firstResult;
                case "FirstOrDefault":
                    return viewSet.FirstOrDefault(filter);

                case "Last":
                    var lastResult = viewSet.LastOrDefault(filter);
                    if (lastResult == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no element matching specified criteria.");
                    }
                    return lastResult;
                case "LastOrDefault":
                    return viewSet.LastOrDefault(filter);
                case "Count":
                    return viewSet.Count(filter);
                case "Any":
                    return viewSet.Any(filter);
                case "All":
                    return viewSet.All(filter);

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Method '" + filterExpression.Method.Name + "' is not currently supported by this provider.");
            }
        }

        var method = expression as MethodCallExpression;
        if (method != null && method.Method.Name == "Select")
        {
            // handle projections
            var lambda = ((UnaryExpression)method.Arguments[1]).Operand as LambdaExpression;
            if (lambda != null)
            {
                var returnType = lambda.ReturnType;
                var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Select");
                var typedGeneric = selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), returnType);
                var result = typedGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { viewSet.ToList().AsQueryable(), lambda }) as IEnumerable;
                return result;
            }
        }

        return viewSet.Select(filter);
    }
}
```

As you can see this class has changed quite dramatically [since when I first wrote it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/119339/23788), and it doesn't look like it's becoming any prettier - especially now that I'm considering adding support for `SelectMany`.

How should I cure it?

Comment: This project doesn't use C# 6 does it?

Comment: @RobH indeed, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things I think when I see a large case statement is would this be better off as some kind of lookup table.  I think yours might have some scope for doing this since they all seem to do some processing on a viewSets and a filter.  Using a simple lookup table to convert the string "Where", "Single" etc into a method call would allow you to separate the logic out a bit more.  So, for example you could do something like this (better naming is left as an exercise for the reader):

```
public static class FilterExpressionHelper
{
    readonly static Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> _methods;

    static FilterExpressionHelper()
    {
        _methods = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();

        foreach(var methodInfo in typeof(FilterExpressionHelper).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).Where(x=>x.Name != "Execute"))
        {
            _methods.Add(methodInfo.Name, methodInfo);
        }
    }

    public static object Execute<T>(string methodName, ViewSet<T> view, string filter)
    {
        if(_methods.ContainsKey(methodName))
            return _methods[methodName].MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(null, new object [] { view, filter });
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Method '{methodName}' is not currently supported by this provider.");
    }

    public static object Where<T>(ViewSet<T> viewSet, string filter)
    {
        return viewSet.Select(filter);
    }
    public static object Single<T>(ViewSet<T> viewSet, string filter)
    {
        var singleResult = viewSet.SingleOrDefault(filter);
        if (singleResult == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains more than one element.");
        }
        return singleResult;
    }
    public static object SingleOrDefault<T>(ViewSet<T> viewSet, string filter)
    {
        return viewSet.SingleOrDefault(filter);
    }
    // etc
}
```

This would allow you to replace the large case statement in your filter logic with:

```
FilterExpressionHelper.Execute(filterExpression.Method.Name, viewSet, filter);
```